# cant get the updated profile info with firebase after signIn with email

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, firebase-authentication

I am currently developping an app using react native and i could manage to have a login and sign up page but my problem is the following.
After create user with email and password using firebase method, i would like to update the profile info (displayName) in order to display it in the home page.
But it seems that the page redirect to the home page after sign up without the update done

I have set a listener on my navigator stack to display login/signup pages or Home page regarding the value of user.

the Update is correctly set if i close the app and reload it after the first sign up success.

my code is the following
the main stack code

```
function onAuthStateChange(user) {
  setUser(user);
  if (initializing) setInitializing(false);
}
useEffect(() => {
  const subscriber = auth().onAuthStateChanged(onAuthStateChange);
  return subscriber;
}, [];

if (initializing) {
return <LoadingScreen />

if (!user) {
return (
  <NavigationCOntainer>
     <AuthStackScreen />
  </NavigationCOntainer>
 );
}

return (
 <NavigationCOntainer>
    <DrawerStackScreen />
 </NavigationCOntainer>
```

the code to handle the sign up method :

```
function handgleRegister() {
  auth()
    .createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
    .then(userCred => {
       return userCred.user.updateProfile({
           displayName: name,
       });
    })
    .catch(e => {
    ...
    ...
    });
}
```

the code in the Home page, i also set a listener of user.
I also have tried by calling the method : auth().currentUser;
But i got the same problem, the displayName at the first display was set to null and i had to close and reload the app to be able to display it.

```
function onAuthStateChange(user) {
  console.log(user);
}
useEffect(() => {
  const subscriber = auth().onAuthStateChanged(onAuthStateChange);
  return subscriber;
}, [];
```

the result of the log shows that displayName is null so i assume the sign up process redirect to the home before updating the value.

Does someone has an idea how i can manage to get the update value on the Home page screen?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3):

The user's profile information is gotten from their ID token, which Firebase gets then the user signs in (or is created) and then automatically refreshes every hour. If the user's profile is updated within that hour, the client may be showing outdated profile information until it refreshes the token.

You can force the refresh of a token by:

1. Signing the user out and in again.
2. Calling [`User.reload`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.User#reload) or [`User.getIdToken(true)`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.User#getidtoken).

Both of these cases force the client to refresh the ID token, and thus get the latest profile from the servers.

Comment: thanks for the answer.
if i wanna use the user.reload method,  how can i implement it in the home page.
should i set also a hook listener on onAuthStateChanged and if user exists, reload it?

Using DB to save the display name, is it better to keep this information updated in realtime?

Answer (score 0):

try this.

```
function handgleRegister() {
  auth()
    .createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
    .then(userCred => {
       userCred.user.updateProfile({
           displayName: name,
       }).then(()=>{
       setUser(auth().currentUser());
    };
    })
    .catch(e => {
    ...
    ...
    });
}
```

here's my signup code. I'm just update the profile with the email address right now since i don't have another input for display name. I'm also using redux toolkit.

```
import React, { Component, useEffect } from "react";
import { View } from "react-native";
import { Button, Input } from "react-native-elements";
import Icon from "react-native-vector-icons/FontAwesome";
import { Dimensions } from "react-native";
import auth from "@react-native-firebase/auth";
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from "react-redux";
import {
  clearLoginInfo,
  updateLoginInfo,
  signInWithEmailAndPassword,
} from "../login/LoginSlice";

export default function SignupScreen(props) {
  const { navigation } = props;
  const [username, setUsername] = React.useState("");
  const [password, setPassword] = React.useState("");
  const [passwordErrorMsg, setPasswordErrorMsg] = React.useState("");
  const [usernameErrorMsg, setUsernameErrorMsg] = React.useState("");
  const [securedText, setSecuredTtext] = React.useState(true);
  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  function onAuthStateChanged(user) {
    console.log("on user change", user);
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    const subscriber = auth().onAuthStateChanged(onAuthStateChanged);
    return subscriber; // unsubscribe on unmount
  }, []);

  const signIn = (e) => {
    auth()
      .createUserWithEmailAndPassword(e.username, e.password)
      .then((user) => {
        console.log("user = ", user);
        user.user
          .updateProfile({
            displayName: e.username,
            photoURL: "abc.com",
          })
          .then(() => {
            const currentUser = auth().currentUser;
            console.log("current user ", auth().currentUser);
            dispatch(
              updateLoginInfo({
                displayName: currentUser.displayName,
                photoURL: currentUser.photoURL,
              })
            );
          });
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        if (error.code === "auth/email-already-in-use") {
          setUsernameErrorMsg("That email address is already in use!");
        }
        if (error.code === "auth/invalid-email") {
          setUsernameErrorMsg("That email address is invalid!");
        }
        if (error.code === "auth/weak-password") {
          setPasswordErrorMsg("please choose a stronger password");
        }

        console.error(error);
      });
  };

  const handlePasswordChange = (val) => {
    setPassword(val);
  };

  const handleUserNameChange = (val) => {
    setUsername(val);
  };

  const doSignin = () => {
    signIn({ username, password });
  };
  return (
    <View
      style={{
        flex: 1,
        justifyContent: "center",
        alignContent: "center",
        alignItems: "center",
      }}
    >
      <Input
        placeholder="Email"
        errorMessage={usernameErrorMsg}
        value={username}
        leftIcon={{ type: "font-awesome", name: "envelope" }}
        onChangeText={handleUserNameChange}
      />
      <Input
        placeholder="Password"
        errorMessage={passwordErrorMsg}
        errorStyle={{ color: "red" }}
        value={password}
        leftIcon={<Icon name="lock" size={40} color="black" />}
        rightIcon={
          securedText ? (
            <Icon
              name="eye"
              size={32}
              onPress={() => setSecuredTtext(!securedText)}
              color="black"
            />
          ) : (
            <Icon
              name="eye-slash"
              size={32}
              onPress={() => setSecuredTtext(!securedText)}
              color="black"
            />
          )
        }
        onChangeText={handlePasswordChange}
        secureTextEntry={securedText}
      />
      <Button
        title="Sign up"
        onPress={() => doSignin()}
        buttonStyle={{ backgroundColor: "#eda621" }}
        style={{ width: Dimensions.get("window").width * 0.5 }}
      />
      <Button
        title="Back to Sign in"
        style={{ width: Dimensions.get("window").width * 0.5, marginTop: 10 }}
        onPress={() => navigation.navigate("Signin")}
      />
    </View>
  );
}
```

listener:

```
useEffect(()=>{
   if (user != null && user.displayName != '') {
     navigation.navigate("Home");
   },
   [user]});
```

Comment: I want to register so i create a new user.
the creation is correct, i can see the new user in the firebase console.
My problem is the update, i cant get the updated values on the first load of the home page after sign up.
i need to close the app and reload it.
It looks like the update is async so i redirect before finishing. But i cant get it to work well..

Comment: so if you put in a console in the onAuthChange, and use a new email to sign up. do you get anything?

Comment: the creation of new user or login work well.  also the error if the email is already use or others error are ok.
The problem is not for the creation of users or login them.
It is only regarding the update of their infos to display them on the first load!

Comment: sorry about that. i just updated my answer. tested it out on my end, and it's working for me.

Comment: the code you modify, i cant use because the handleregister function  doesnt have the setUser hook.
this register function doesnt need a user value.
It only handle the sign up process 
the listener for the user is in App.js and here the setUser hook is used to check if a user is logged or not to display the proper route.

Comment: you can easily pass that in as a callback?

Comment: Ok i see, u using redux and i dont.
By using it, can u get the updated username value in the home page route.
once u created the new user, does ur app move to a Home page?

Comment: yes, i have a listener on the user object. If user is not null, it will automatically navigate to the Home screen.

Comment: Thanks for the answers.
what about the state u define in your reducers, did u define a user object to contain the user from firebase?
on App.js, on the onAuthStateCHanged listener, do u have a dispatcher to modify the user state value?

Moreover, dont u have a delay on the display? as the createNewUserWithEmail will  return the user object before the update is done. It means u will reach Home page before the update.

i copy ur code (without the UPD dispatch), just with the logs. I also put a log in my home page and it displays the home log before the log with the current user updated.

Comment: in my redux store, I simply have the display name and photo URL. I'm still at the very beginning of developing the project, so everything is very simple right now. You are right that there's a delay in displaying the user name, so i would probably move the navigate within the then() of the update profile just to wait for it to finish before navigating to the home page.

Comment: HI,
thanks for the details.
Indeed the delay is here for me as well. I could manage to have a shorter delay by using firebase DB,  but it would be great is firebase team could modify their createUser method to use the name we input when we create a new user. most of the app ask for a name.

moving the navigate in the then won't break the listener on user in App.js and make the use of the stack navigator useless?

I am thinking to use a state boolean value (such as ready), modify the ready value after the updateand  to check when the user is created and ready = true then show the Home.

Comment: see my latest update to the listener if you don't want to move the navigate into the .then() and remove the listener.

Comment: Hi,
the listener with the check on the displayName, do u put this code in the App.js or in the register page?

Comment: I put that in the login page since that's the first page that loads in my app.