# Firebase V9 with React Native - Display Name updating too slow

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native

I am new to react, firebase and stack overflow so please bear with me.
I'm trying to create a user registration form with firebase that includes a 'name' input. It does work to update the display name, but not fast enough to show the name when the user first logs in. I need to save the homescreen.js file and then the display name populates.

code from registerscreen.js

```
 const [name, setName] = useState('')

const handleRegister = async () => {
if (confirmPass !== password){
  alert('Passwords Do Not Match')
  return false}
  else{
}
try{ 
const user = await createUserWithEmailAndPassword(auth, email, password)
updateProfile(auth.currentUser, {displayName: name}) 
console.log('logged in with', user.email)
} catch (error) {
    alert(error.message);
}
```

and here is the text on the homescreen.js to display the users name:

```
 <Text style={styles.text}>Logged in as {auth.currentUser?.displayName}</Text>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you have two good options.

1. Save the user's display name locally when they register, for example in Context or AsyncStorage, and use that on your logged-in screen.  In AsyncStorage, that would look something like this:

```js
  // registerscreen.js
  await AsyncStorage.setItem('name', name);

  // homescreen.js body
  const name = await AsyncStorage.getItem('name');
  // homescreen.js return
  <Text style={styles.text}>Logged in as {auth.currentUser?.displayName || name}</Text>
```

[Docs for AsyncStorage are here.](https://reactnative.dev/docs/asyncstorage)

2. Show a loading indicator until your Firebase request comes back with the display name.

```js
  // homescreen.js body
  // get auth object, however you are doing this already
  const auth = await getAuth();
  // homescreen.js return
  return (
   auth?.currentUser
     ? // your current component here
     : <LoadingScreen />
  );
```

LoadingScreen could be something like

```js
  <View style={[StyleSheet.absoluteFill, { justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center'>
    <LoadingIndicator />
  </View>
```

Comment: Would you mind showing me what either of  those would look like in my code? I am a noob with javascript.

Comment: sure, added examples

Answer (score 0):

Just like `createUserWithEmailAndPassword`, the call to `updateProfile is an asynchronous call, so you'll want to await until it's done:

```
await updateProfile(auth.currentUser, {displayName: name})
```

Comment: This only works if the user signs out and back in, essentially refreshing the page. The name does not show when they initially are directed to the home page after submitting the registration form

Comment: Aha... for that you'll need to refresh the user. See a.o. https://stackoverflow.com/a/64355958/209103